# Get-mailboxpermissions limitation?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to get a list of all users on my system along with their mail permissions, to do this i'm using:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication  Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 

$outList = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -ResultSize unlimited 
$outList | Select-Object -Property identity, User, AccessRights, IsInherited, Deny | Export-Csv -path c:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This works fine however when it finished running I noticed it stopped at the H's around row 17,000 (there are a lot of user/permissions) is there a way to force this to complete for all users or is there a limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was with `$outList = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -ResultSize unlimited`

it was missing `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue relates to not using `-resultsize unlimited`

If you add this parameter then your output will contain full results